# Returning trigonometric value answers in irrational form

Tags: trigonometry

I need to find the irrational form of `Sin[7*\[Pi]/8]`. But in Mathematica, I can get its numerical value. I am getting

```
Sin[\[Pi]/4]=1/Sqrt[2]
```

in Mathematica. What I meant is an answer something like this for `Sin[7*\[Pi]/8]` as well. Is that possible?

Comment: it is hard to understand what you are asking. But if you mean you want Mathematica not to automatically write `Sin[Pi/4]` as `1/Sqrt[2]`, you can check this answer  [prevent-simplification-of-trig-functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192371/prevent-simplification-of-trig-functions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following does the job.

```
Sin[7*\[Pi]/8] // ToRadicals
```

> `Sqrt[2 - Sqrt[2]]/2`